# Can't connect to my AWS Database Instance | psql: could not connect to server: Operation timed out

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I created a postgres DB instance on AWS RDS. I am trying to connect this DB instance to my django zappa app so I can perform AWS Lambda functions.

I've added a new security group to my DB instance so I can allow my django app to connect to it:

[image]

My DB details show that the new security group is active:

[image]

However when I try to connect to it, either by running `psql --host="*************.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com" --port="5432" --username="*********" --password --dbname="*****"` via my terminal,

or via my pgadmin interface, it returns this error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
    Is the server running on host "***********.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com" (18.191.94.44) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Any idea why it does this?

Comment: Is your application running in the same VPC?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking but my zappa app is a local django project that is trying to connect to the RDS database. I'm following the instructions on this tutorial: https://cloudacademy.com/blog/zappa-or-how-to-go-serverless-with-django/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The most common error is not having allowed yourself access/not set to public accessibility.

1. Ensure that the RDS DB instance was marked as [publicly accessible](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.html#USER_VPC.Hiding) (change to YES.

> Select Yes if you want EC2 instances and devices outside of the VPC hosting the DB instance to connect to the DB instance. If you select No, Amazon RDS will not assign a public IP address to the DB instance, and no EC2 instance or devices outside of the VPC will be able to connect. If you select Yes, you must also select one or more VPC security groups that specify which EC2 instances and devices can connect to the DB instance.

2. Make sure you've allowed yourself access in the [Security Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html) of the RDS database. You should add or change the current inbound rule to allows your ip (or 0.0.0.0/0 as a last resort - **anyone on the internet will be able to connect**) to access the RDS on your port. By default the outbound rule is already set as 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Yep I've ensured the instance is publicly accessible. As for the second point, is that the IP of my computer? So I would add the IP of my computer to the "Destination" part of "Outbound" in my security group? PS: "Destination is already set to `0.0.0.0/0` and still not working so something else must be wrong.

Comment: You also have to change inbound in security group to 0.0.0.0/0

Note that this is very unsecured so do not use it for prod app. The recommended and secured way is to query the DB from a rest API on AWS API Gateway and then the rest API query the database.

Answer (score 2):

Check:

https://medium.com/overlander/connecting-to-rds-from-local-over-tcp-operation-timed-out-5cfc819f402c

Is our RDS instance able to send responses back to us?
Check that your RDS instance is in a public subnet. A public subnet is one whose route table directs some traffic out to the public via an internet gateway. If you want to connect to an RDS instance from a public address, the instance must in a public subnet.