# CORS issue when connecting AWS Amplify frontend to AWS Elastic Beanstalk backend

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, vue.js, flask, cors

**Background:** I have the frontend (Vue) of my app deployed on AWS Amplify and the Backend (Python) on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. My frontend is connected to the backend via Axios.

**Problem:** When sending data from the front end to the backend, I get a `CORS error Access to XMLHttpRequest at '***' from origin '***' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

When my frontend is sending data to the localhost, there's no issue, so I don't think it's an issue with my code. Is there something about the Elastic Beanstalk configuration I need to change?

I'm not sure what all code I need to include to get a proper answer, so please let me know what you'd like to see and I can update the question appropriately. I've added my `application.py` code below and am using Flask-CORS currently.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask import request, session
from flask_cors import CORS
import os
from common.api import api
from journal_blueprint import journal_blueprint
from manuscript_blueprint import manuscript_blueprint
from user_blueprint import user_blueprint
from models.decorators import requires_login
from models.user import User
from models.manuscript import Manuscript
from models.journal import Journal
from config_file import BaseConfig

application=Flask(__name__)

application.secret_key = BaseConfig.SECRET_KEY
application.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ["DATABASE_URL"]

CORS(application)

application.register_blueprint(journal_blueprint, url_prefix='/journal')
application.register_blueprint(user_blueprint, url_prefix='/user')
application.register_blueprint(manuscript_blueprint, url_prefix='/manuscript')
application.register_blueprint(api, url_prefix="/api")


@application.route('/')
def home_template():
    return render_template('index.html')


@application.route('/login')
def login_template():
    return render_template('user/login.html')


@application.route('/register')
def register_template():
    return render_template('user/register.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # application.run(debug=True)
    application.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration looks fine. Please look for errors in the elasticbeantalk logs. It is possible that the application throws some errors in the elasticbeanstalk environment, during which the CORS headers are not returned.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't consider looking at the EB logs. When I did, I came across this error `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection timed out`. I was able to fix the issue by adding an inbound rule to the security group allowing all traffic from 0.0.0.0/0. However, reading the answer here:[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50984887/cant-connect-to-my-aws-database-instance-psql-could-not-connect-to-server-o] indicates this isn't a good solution for prod since it's not secure. Any ideas on how to make this a more secure solution?

Comment: ya its not a good idea to allow all the traffic especially when your database is publicly accessible. where is your database is running. are you using amazon RDS ? If you are running the database with in the AWS network, In the database security group, you could allow port 5432 from the application security group as the source. thats the most secure way.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#SecurityGroupRule